# What does Overcompleteness mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning sparse coding currently. And one of its famous paper mentioned overcompleteness. When I find overcompleteness's explanation in wiki, I find it too complicated to understand. Could someone explain to me?

Comment: Do you know what Banach space is ?

Comment: I don't quite understand it after reading wiki.

Comment: Do you know what a normed linear space is?

Comment: I know normed linear space, but am not familiar with Banach space, where it is defined as complete normed linear space, according to http://grizzly.la.psu.edu/~rxz9/normed-linear-space.pdf.

Comment: In finite dimensions, a system of vectors is overcomplete if it contains a basis of the underlying space as a proper subset.